# Problem with String to Date Conversion

Tags: java, mysql, grails, date, groovy

I am trying to convert date in String format to sql date and based on that query database to get the result.
Date in string format is :`2011-08-11 09:16:00.0` 
So I am converting it to sql date by using the method:

```
public static convertStringToSqlDate(String dateString){
    DateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    java.util.Date parsedUtilDate = formater.parse(dateString);
    java.sql.Date sqlDate= new java.sql.Date(parsedUtilDate.getTime());
    return sqlDate;
}
```

The resulting date is :2011-08-11

but while doing the query I am not getting desired output

The complete code is

```
def startDate = params. startDate
def endDate = params. endDate
def formattedTripStartDate  =Trip.convertStringToSqlDate(startDate);
def formattedTripEndDate    =Trip.convertStringToSqlDte(endDate);
def listOfContracts = Rule.findAll("FROM Rule WHERE name LIKE ? AND client_id = ? AND STR_TO_DATE(contract_begins,'%Y-%m-%d')<= ? AND STR_TO_DATE(contract_terminates,'%Y-%m-%d')>= ?",["%"+q_param+"%",clientId,formattedTripStartDate,formattedTripEndDate] )
```

Where am I going wrong?

In database the contract_begins is stored as :2011-08-23 00:00:00

Contract domain Class is

```
class Contract extends Rule {

Date    contractBegins
Date    contractTerminates
int     runningDays
Double  contractValue
Double  estimatedRevenue
Double  actualRevenue
static constraints = {
    contractBegins(nullable:true)
    contractTerminates(nullable:true)
    runningDays(nullable:true)
    contractValue(nullable:true)
    estimatedRevenue(nullable:true)
    actualRevenue(nullable:true)
}
  }
```

Comment: "Sting" is an ageing rock-star.  You probably mean "String"...

Comment: why to store date as String in DB

Comment: as Jigar Joshi said, you should be storing dates as dates in your DB

Comment: @Hussy then why are you doing: "STR_TO_DATE".   By the way there is not enough information to guess what is wrong.  Show the data in your database, explain the data types for each field.

Comment: ok i will update the code... i will add Contract domain class

Answer (score 0):

Date object didn't format by itself, it return only date and time value. you can get the formatted by only Format supported class in string format like SimpleDateFormat, DateFormat etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use a findAll query, and not a criteria. Something like this should do it:

```
def startDate = params.startDate
def endDate = params.endDate
def tripStartDate=Trip.convertStringToSqlDate(startDate);
def eripEndDate=Trip.convertStringToSqlDte(endDate);

def c = Contract.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
    like("name", "%${q_param}%")
    eq("client_id", clientId) 
    ge('contract_begins', tripStartDate)
    le('contract_terminates','tripEndDate) 
}
```

It's much cleaner and you don't have to worry about how the SQL looks like!

Take a deep dive into http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html and http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.4.2 Criteria where you can find much more information.

Also consider making your code even nicer by adding the criteria into the Domain Class named queries: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.springpeople.steer.trips.TripController.after() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.sql.Date) values: [contract_begins, 2011-08-12]

Comment: I fixed the code - have not tried if it works, but it could :-)

Comment: [2011-08-12 18:22:58:203] ERROR groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver ### could not resolve property: client_id of: com.springpeople.steer.rules.Contract
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: client_id of: com.springpeople.steer.rules.Contract

Comment: client is defined in Rule not in Contract , Contract extends Rule

Comment: Well, if Contract extends Rule, then it should be accessible in Contract, and thus it should be queryable. I did not say, that my code was tested, but it was ment as an example. Please read the documentation.